# Dynamically change style of variable displayed in vue component

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

i have a div that is displaying elements using v-for, like that

```
<div v-for"element in example" :id="element+'id'">
{{element}}
</div>
```

the elements have unique ids as you can see.
And everything is working but i have on specific moment when it needs to be styles differently. 
When the current element contains ['some text'] in brackets like that i want to assign a style to this specific text, not the whole element only the text in brackets. Is there easy way for this, or?

Comment: better to make fiddle or working sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply some styling if the ternary (? operator) returns true. Otherwise don't apply any styles at all.

```
<div v-for"element in example" :id="element+'id'" :style="element.includes('[some text]') ? 'custom-css-styles-here' : ''">
    {{ element }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass your verification in a tenary operation

```
<div v-for"element in example" :id="element+'id'" :class="element.includes('[some text]') ? 'color-red' : 'color-blue'">
  {{element}}
</div>
```

I don't really understand your verification but if you give me the release I can do the operation